# How to create a logical backup of a relational table in mysql workbench using mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-backup

How do I put these codes in MySQL workbench to create a logical backup of a BOOK table without using the command line? I put the codes below in the workbench and it shows an error: "mysqldump" is not valid at this position.

```
mysqldump [arguments] > file-name


mysqldump csit115 BOOK --user csit115 --password
--verbose --lock_tables > book.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

Physical backups consist of raw copies of the directories and files that store database contents. This type of backup is suitable for large, important databases that need to be recovered quickly when problems occur.

Logical backups save information represented as logical database structure (CREATE DATABASE, CREATE TABLE statements) and content (INSERT statements or delimited-text files). This type of backup is suitable for smaller amounts of data where you might edit the data values or table structure, or recreate the data on a different machine architecture.

Comment: can you show an example of creating a logical backup in MySQL workbench with mysqldump? preferably a pictorial example